# Substitution of Thread.suspend() method

Tags: java, multithreading

Hi I am working with threads in java, I have the next code which has a graphic interface with a button, and a textArea. It also uses one thread, when I run the thread with thread1.start() it starts printing a counter every 2 seconds (prints 0,1,2,3,etc..), the interface implements an actionListener too, when I click the button the thread must suspend the execution. But my problem is that the method Thread.suspend() is deprecated, and I don´t know which other way can I work this out.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


class thread extends Thread{
    private int count;
    private long seconds;
    private boolean keepPrinting = true;
    private JTextArea textArea;

    thread(int sec,int c,JTextArea text){
        count = c;
        seconds = sec;
        textArea = text;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        while(keepPrinting)
        {
            try
            {
                print();
                sleep(seconds);
                count++;
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void print() {
        String j;
        j = Integer.toString(count);
        textArea.setText(j);     
    }
}

class Interface extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    private JTextArea text;
    private JButton button;
    private JPanel window;
    private thread thread1;

    Interface()
    {
        text = new JTextArea(10,10);
        button = new JButton("Ejecutar");
        window = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        window.add("South",text);
        window.add("North",button);
        thread1 = new thread(2000,0,text);
        this.add(window);

        thread1.start();

        button.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {

    }   

}


public class MensajesHilos {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Interface i = new Interface();
        i.setTitle("Threads");
        i.setBounds(200, 200, 300, 310);
        i.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, for starts, you are violating the single thread rules of Swing, but updating the UI from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.  You could use a monitor lock to hold the `Thread` execution until it's released

Answer (score 0):

1. Swing is not thread safe, all updates to the UI must be made from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread. See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.  In your case, it might be easier to use a `SwingWorker`, but we'll run with this...
2. You're generally discouraged from extending directly from `Thread`, you are encouraged to implement `Runnable` and pass an instance of this to an instance of a `Thread` instead.
3. You can control a thread's execution through the use of some kind of lock.  You use either the original `Object#wait` and `Object#notify` API or the more recent concurrency `Lock` API.  For simplicity, I'm using the older version.  Take a look at [Intrinsic Locks and Synchronization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) and [Lock Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html) for more details
4. Variables which need to be inspected by multiple threads should either be made `volatile` or you should use one of the equivalent `Atomic` classes.  For the `Atomic` classes, this ensures that reads and writes to the value are done cleanly (only one thread at a time). Take a look at [Atomic Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomicvars.html)

For example...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static class Worker implements Runnable {

        private int count;
        private long seconds;
        private JTextArea textArea;

        private AtomicBoolean keepRunning = new AtomicBoolean(true);
        private AtomicBoolean paused = new AtomicBoolean(false);

        protected static final Object PAUSE_LOCK = new Object();

        public Worker(int sec, int c, JTextArea text) {
            count = c;
            seconds = sec;
            textArea = text;
        }

        public void stop() {
            keepRunning.set(false);
            setPaused(false);
        }

        public void setPaused(boolean value) {

            if (paused.get() != value) {

                paused.set(value);
                if (!value) {
                    synchronized (PAUSE_LOCK) {
                        PAUSE_LOCK.notifyAll();
                    }
                }

            }

        }

        protected void checkPausedState() {

            while (paused.get() && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                System.out.println("I be paused");
                synchronized (PAUSE_LOCK) {
                    try {
                        PAUSE_LOCK.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        public void run() {
            while (keepRunning.get() && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

                checkPausedState();

                if (keepRunning.get() && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

                    try {
                        System.out.println(count);
                        print(count);
                        Thread.sleep(seconds);
                        count++;
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        public void print(final int j) {
            if (EventQueue.isDispatchThread()) {
                textArea.append(Integer.toString(j) + "\n");
            } else {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        print(j);
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        protected boolean isPaused() {
            return paused.get();
        }
    }

    public static class UI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

        private JTextArea text;
        private JButton button;
        private Worker worker;

        public UI() {
            text = new JTextArea(10, 10);
            button = new JButton("Pause/Resume");
            add(text);
            add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            worker = new Worker(2000, 0, text);

            Thread t = new Thread(worker);
            t.start();

            button.addActionListener(this);
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            worker.setPaused(!worker.isPaused());
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                UI frame = new UI();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```